# Problem with PATH set up during PostgreSQL 9.1 installation on Debian virtual machine

Tags: postgresql, installation, debian, postgresql-9.1

I followed steps in installation guide of PostgreSQL on my Debian virtual machine, but when I'm trying to use initdb and pg_ctl commands OS tells me that there's no such command. What I did:

1. Installed PostgreSQL 9.1 `apt-get update` and `apt-get install postgresql-9.1` with root user.
2. Created `data` folder with `mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/data`
3. Edited `/etc/environment` file with 2 lines:
   `PATH+="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin"
   PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/data"`

I see initdb and pg_ctl in bin folder, but yet I'm getting

`pg_ctl: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you installing and outdated and unmaintained Postgres version?

Comment: Because when I'm trying to install `apt-get install postgresql-10` I'm getting **E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.** error

Comment: Then try to fix _that_ instead of using an unsupported and outdated version. 9.1 has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for 2 years now. At least use some more up-to-date e.g. 9.6 or 9.5 if you can't fix your broken packages.

Comment: I'm getting the same broken packages error when I'm trying to install `apt-get install postgresql-9.6`

Answer (score 0):

When updating your PATH env variable, it should be as “PATH=/path/your/adding:$PATH” not “PATH+=...”

Comment: I've tried to change it to `PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin:$PATH` and `PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin:$PATH"`, but after reboot system stuck at the login screen, after entering my credentials screen just blinks for a second and returns to the login screen.

Comment: you need to export the PATH variable maybe
i.e. export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin:$PATH